# Multi-GPU programming with multi-(CPU)threads

Tags: multithreading, cuda

I have application which is embarrassingly parallel. Is it possible to launch multiple CPU threads so that a thread manages a GPU?If it is possible, what threading library should I use on CPU side? OpenMP?Pthreads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but since Cuda 4.0 was released, unnecessary. The Cuda API is now thread safe, so you can asynchronously manage multiple devices using a single host thread.

If you really want to use multiple host threads, just about any host library will do. I have successfully used pthreads, boost::thread and Apple's grand central dispatch with Cuda on linux  and OS X.

Comment: So is it possible to manage ith CUDA device with ith thread so that ith CPU thread sends ith chunk of my data to ith device?

Comment: Yes, nothing special is required. The only thing you need to be careful about is making sure each thread gets a unique GPU. For that, either have a master thread enumerate all the devices and assign and broadcast device IDs to each thread, or use the compute exclusive settings in the TCC/Linux driver and let the driver automagically assign a device to each thread.

Comment: can you please elaborate compute exclusive settings in TCC?

Comment: you can use the `-c` option in `nvidia-smi` to set the GPU to compute exclusive mode, although I seem to remember that was the default anyway. There is/was a TCC driver whitepaper which explains everything about the driver and its settings.

Comment: What happens if each host thread does not get a unique GPU? Does it result in crash/undefined behavior?